# Issues using jqGrid 3.6.4 and jQuery 1.4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Given the wide array of features jqGrid offers, has anyone run into issues using the latest jqGrid 3.6.4 with jQuery 1.4?

Comment: Not really sure that this is a great question, I mean jqGrid 3.6.4 is built to work with jQuery 1.4 right? Seems strange to ask about using the two of them together.

Comment: The release says 'Again with this we fixed jqModal and jqDnR to be compatible with jQuery 1.4.x versions', but nothing of the rest of the jqGrid feature set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have any issues with jqGrid 3.6.4 & jQuery 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't noticed any yet, but I have gotten problems with other plugins.  JQuery Plugin developers seem to be shaking the bugs out of their plugins since the update.